# Should I use two servers for SPA Rails app with Vue.js Frontend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I'm building a SPA Rails 5 application with a Vue.js frontend. Currently I send my Vue.js `build.js` file to my JavaScript's folder in my Rails app. My routes file is below:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'application#index'

  namespace :api do
    resource :users, only: :create
    get '/activate-account/:token', to: 'users#activate_account', 
                                    as: 'activate_account'
    resource :session, only: [:create, :destroy]
    get '/password-reminder', to: 'users#password_reminder'
    post '/password-reset', to: 'users#password_reset'
  end

  get '/*path', to: 'application#index'
end
```

I also have my Vue.js routes set up using VueRouter. Everything is working fine where if none of my Rails API routes get hit the build.js file is served and the appropriate Vue route is used.

My question is how do I set up this application so that I can use Rails API only mode. Would I need to to have two different servers running on different urls?

Comment: In my experience, we've always used a separate API server and frontend server for making scalable and maintainable SPAs. My last project was had a rails backend, and it was API only, with a Vue SPA frontend. Yes, their servers need to be run separately.

Comment: Thanks wrahim. That definitely helps. Did you use a separate domain for the two servers?

Comment: In our case we did, for example, frontend would be accessed with yourdomain.com, and it would make requests to the backend at api-yourdomain.com/v1/. But I've also worked on projects where the frontend and backend has the same domain, under a different route: e.g. yourdomain.com/api/v1/, or even subdomains: api.yourdomain.com/v1/

Comment: Thanks wrahim! I appreciate the help.